# Difference between Kubernetes Objects and Resources

Tags: kubernetes

What is the difference between Objects and Resouces in Kubernetes world?

I couldn't find it from https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/ . I wonder they make no distinction about them but seems they see objects as a high-level concept of resources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- A [Kubernetes object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/) is a persistent entities in the Kubernetes system.
- A [Kubernetes resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) is an endpoint in the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/) that stores a collection of [API objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/) of a certain kind; for example, the built-in pods resource contains a collection of Pod objects.

### Objects

Kubernetes uses these entities to represent the state of your cluster.
Specifically, they can describe:

- What containerized applications are running (and on which nodes)
- The resources available to those applications
- The policies around how those applications behave, such as restart policies, upgrades, and fault-tolerance

A Kubernetes object is a "record of intent"--once you create the object, the Kubernetes system will constantly work to ensure that object exists.
By creating an object, you're effectively telling the Kubernetes system what you want your cluster's workload to look like; this is your cluster's desired state.

Note: as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309496/difference-between-kubernetes-objects-and-resources/64127713?noredirect=1#comment118432908_64127713) by [VASャ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9521610/vas%E3%83%A3):

> Objects usually don't disappear from the cluster on their own, with one exception:
>
> if you create a Pod object manually, and it is scheduled on a node:
>
> - it will be completely vanished from the cluster after some time, in case of the node failure or shut down, and
> - the Pod won't be recreated on another node as you may expect

### Resource

A resource is part of a [declarative API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#declarative-apis), used by Kubernetes client libraries and CLIs, or `kubectl`.
It can lead to "custom resource", an extension of the Kubernetes API that is not necessarily available in a default Kubernetes installation.

Comment: Objects usually don't disappear from the cluster on their own, with one exception: if you create a Pod object manually, and it is scheduled on a node, it will be completely vanished from the cluster after some time, in case of the node failure or shut down, and the Pod won't be recreated on another node as you may expect.

Comment: @VASャ Good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 18):

A representation of a specific group+version+kind is an object. For example, a v1 Pod, or an apps/v1 Deployment. Those definitions can exist in manifest files, or be obtained from the apiserver.

A specific URL used to obtain the object is a resource. For example, a list of v1 Pod objects can be obtained from the `/api/v1/pods` resource. A specific v1 Pod object can be obtained from the `/api/v1/namespaces/<namespace-name>/pods/<pod-name>` resource.

API discovery documents (like the one published at /api/v1) can be used to determine the resources that correspond to each object type.

Often, the same object can be retrieved from and submitted to multiple resources. For example, v1 Pod objects can be submitted to the following resource URLs:

1. `/api/v1/namespaces/<namespace-name>/pods/<pod-name>`
2. `/api/v1/namespaces/<namespace-name>/pods/<pod-name>/status`

Distinct resources allow for different server-side behavior and access control. The first URL only allows updating parts of the pod spec and metadata. The second URL only allows updating the pod status, and access is typically only given to kubelets.

Authorization rules are based on the resources for particular requests.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. btw, how about Custom Resource/Custom Resource Definition? It's obviously a representation of kubernetes entity, Object. Should they be Custom Object...?

Comment: They result in a definition of a particular resource endpoint, along with the object that resource accepts/returns

Answer (score 16):

Kubernetes Objects - are something like order in the restaurant. You define a state of the cluster you want to get finally, just like an order to a waiter. `kubectl` defines your order and delivers it to a cook, just like a waiter. And the API Server prepares your order just like a cook. You define objects in .yaml or .json files.

So, resources are something like menu items. Imagine the Pod is a meat. Meat could be cooked different ways: fried or boiled, for example, but finally it will be a meat in both cases. The similar with the Kubernetes resources. `StatefulSet` will create Pods with fixed names from 0 to N, while `Deployment` won't. `DaemonSet` will create Pods on the each of you nodes, while `Deployment` or `StatefulSet` will create as many Pods, as you point in replicas. But finally it will be the Pods, no matter what you chose. You might want to order fried meat, but medium-rare with mustard. What the restaurant will do with your order if it was not in item list? You are Welcome to Kubernetes CRD or `CustomResourceDefinition`.

P.S: it's a very abstract description and actually `StatefulSet/DaemonSets/Deployments` or `Ingress` are also the objects, but they are often referred to as the "resources"

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually I wrote this question during I was searching for a generic term of entity in kind field of manifest. I'd like to use Object but Resource is often used in Kubernetes documents.

Answer (score 4):

As we tried to explain in our [blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-deep-dive-api-server-part-1/), resources are representations of a system entity sent or retrieved as JSON via HTTP and objects are the respective in-memory Golang structs along with functions and methods defined on them.

Note that, in general and informally we're using the terms resources and objects interchangeably and that's totally fine. Unless you're a Go developer, [extending Kubernetes](https://301.sh/2018-gopherconuk-slides), you probably don't need to bother at all.

Comment: Thank you for insightful answer and blog post. I'd use Resource in relief.

Answer (score 2):

*Kubernetes Objects* are persistent entities in the Kubernetes system that (collectively) records the desired (intent) and actual states of a Kubernetes cluster.

Most Kubernetes Objects have two fields - `spec` describing the desired state, and `status` describing the actual/current state. The `spec` can be specified by a user or automation tool outside of Kubernetes, or be modified within Kubernetes using *controllers* and *operators*. The `status` is updated by Kubernetes.

Objects are usually represented/visualized as `.yaml`.

---

The serialized state of every Object exists as data in the `etcd` store. You can see these objects in `etcd` using `etcdctl`.

Different Objects describes different concepts and stores different data structures - A `Node` Object needs to store a Kubernetes node's IP address, a `ReplicaSet` Object needs to store the number of desired replicas. A *kind* is a data structure with a name - a named schema for data structures that describes its properties and values.

A Object must belong to a kind. The kind of an Object defines the type of Object it is. For example, the an object is a Pod precisely because its kind is `Pod`.

---

Kubernetes Objects are managed via the *Kubernetes API*. Since the Kubernetes API is a RESTful HTTP API, we adopt the REST/HTTP terminology when talking about the Kubernetes API. Kubernetes Objects is not a concept in REST or HTTP APIS, and thus also doesn't exists in the Kubernetes API; to manage Kubernetes Objects, we must interact with its corresponding Kubernetes API *resource*.

> In the Kubernetes API, all Objects are represented as *resources*. But the opposite is not true - not all Kubernetes API resources represents Objects. For example, resources in the `meta`/`meta.k8s.io` *API group* (e.g. `APIVersions`) does not correspond to any Kubernetes Object. Many sub-resources (e.g. `/pods/<name>/status`) corresponds to *simple kinds* which are not Objects.

Resource type names are lowercase (e.g. `persistentvolumeclaim`), collections uses the plural form of the resource type (e.g. `persistentvolumeclaims`), and kinds are written in CamelCase and singular (e.g. `PersistentVolumeClaim`).

In a typical RESTful HTTP API, you may interact with resources like 'users' or 'transactions' through endpoints like `PATCH /users/9237` or `POST /transaction`. Likewise, you can interact with the Kubernetes API by making HTTP requests to resource endpoints like `GET /api/v1/pods` (to get all objects of kind `Pod`) or `GET /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes` (to get all Objects of kind `NodeMetrics`).

```
$ kubectl get --raw /api/v1/pods
```

Some URLs get a *collection* of resources (usually of the same *resource type*). For example, `kubectl get --raw /api/v1/namespaces/` will return a `PodList` (a collection of Pod resources). Other URLs will get a single resource. For example, `GET /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{name}` will return a single Pod resource.

An Object may be altered via different resources (e.g. a Pod Object may be altered by changing the specification of a `replicaset` or `deployment` resource).

Answer (score 1):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/

A **resource type** is the **name** used in the **Kubernates API**,

- **objects** is the **resource types** which represent a **concrete** instance of a concept on the cluster
- other **resource types** are **virtual**
- A single instance of the resource type is called a **resource**

> Most **Kubernetes API resource types** are **objects**: they represent a
> concrete instance of a concept on the cluster, like a pod or
> namespace. A smaller number of API resource types are "**virtual**" - they
> often represent operations rather than objects, such as a permission
> check.

Answer (score -1):

I also found API Convention of Kubernetes. https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/api-conventions.md#types-kinds