# Unexpected results from clientset.AuthorizationV1().SelfSubjectAccessReviews().Create()

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I'm trying to incorporate the `kubectl auth can-i` [logic](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubectl/cmd/auth/cani.go#L236) into my code base, but while the code is working, the results are not what I expect.

I have 2 users (**minikube**/**jenny**). **minikube** has full cluster wide access, but **jenny** is limited to a namespaced role/rolebinding:

```sh
kubectl create role "jenny-pod-creator" --verb=create --resource=pod -n "jenny"
kubectl create rolebinding "jenny-creator-binding" --role="jenny-pod-creator" --user="jenny" --namespace="jenny"
```

Using the cli, I get the results I expect:

```sh
$ kubectl auth can-i create pod --context jenny -n jenny
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i create pod --context jenny -n default
no - RBAC: role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "jenny-pod-creator" not found
```

but in my code, **jenny** is not coming up with permission to create. `response.Status.Allowed` is always `false` for **jenny** *(always true for **minikube**)*

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    authorizationv1 "k8s.io/api/authorization/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func main() {
    kubeconfig := filepath.Join(
        os.Getenv("HOME"), ".kube", "config",
    )
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    a := clientset.AuthorizationV1().SelfSubjectAccessReviews()
    sar := &authorizationv1.SelfSubjectAccessReview{
        Spec: authorizationv1.SelfSubjectAccessReviewSpec{
            ResourceAttributes: &authorizationv1.ResourceAttributes{
                Namespace: "jenny",
                Verb:      "create",
                Resource:  "Pod",
            },
        },
    }
    response, err := a.Create(context.TODO(), sar, metav1.CreateOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("create resource POD is %v \n", response.Status.Allowed)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kubernetes there's a notion of Kinds and Resources. It's very well explained in [Difference between Kubernetes Objects and Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52309496/difference-between-kubernetes-objects-and-resources) and in [API Conventions](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#types-kinds), if your curious to learn more.

In short:

1. *Kind* is the type which tells a client what kind of entity it represents, and this is always upper case, `Pod` for example.
2. *Resource* is the representation of such entity sent via HTTP, and this is always lower case and plural.

In your case, you're working with *Resource* so you need to change `Pod` (*Kind*) to `pods` (*resource*), which should give you `true` for `jenny`. As for minikube, you're getting always `true` because that user is system:admin, which has full access to the cluster.